How to get SEPOLIA for development without having 0.001 ETH on Mainnet?
I am a student and trying to get some SEPOLIA for development but now on every Faucet there is a condition that your account must hold 0.001 ETH(approx) on the Mainnet to send a request to faucet. So , can anyone give some links through which i could get some SEPOLIA for development

You can use the Google Cloud Web3 faucet or the Chainlink Faucet.
